# How to unmarshal this complex Json data with Golang func json.Unmarshal?

Tags: json, go, unmarshalling

I have the json object like this :

```
{  
  "action":"GetLoad",
  "resource_id":"lb-cdvyel0v",
  "ret_code":0,
  "meter_set":[  
      {  
        "data_set":[  
            {  
              "data":[  
                  [  
                    1478672400,
                    [  
                        1,
                        0
                    ]
                  ],
                  [  
                    1,
                    0
                  ],
                  [  
                    0,
                    0
                  ],
                  [  
                    8,
                    0
                  ],
                  [  
                    1,
                    0
                  ]
              ],
              "eip_id":"eip-jf79ljt7"
            },
            {  
              "data":[  
                  [  
                    1478693280,
                    [  
                        0,
                        0
                    ]
                  ],
                  [  
                    1,
                    0
                  ],
                  [  
                    0,
                    0
                  ]
              ],
              "eip_id":"eip-mw6n6wg0"
            }
        ],
        "meter_id":"uaffic"
      }
  ]
}
```

and I  try to solve the problem like this:

```
type CommonResponse struct {                                                                             
    Action  string `json:"action"`
    JobID   string `json:"job_id"`
    RetCode int    `json:"ret_code"`
    Message string `json:"message"`
}

type GetLoadResponse struct {
    MeterSet   []LoadMeter `json:"meter_set"`
    ResourceId string              `json:"resource_id"`
    CommonResponse
}
type LoadMeter struct {                                                                          
    MeterID string              `json:"meter_id"`
    DataSet LoadDataSet `json:"data_set"`
}     

type LoadDataSet struct {
    EipID string        `json:"eip_id"`
    Data  []interface{} `json:"data"`
}     

func Get(response interface{}) {
    str := `{ "action": "GetLoad", "resource_id": "lb-cdvyel0v",   "ret_code": 0, "meter_set": [ { "data_set": [ { "data": [ [ 1478672400, [ 1, 0 ] ], [ 1, 0 ], [ 0, 0 ], [ 8, 0 ], [ 1, 0 ] ], "eip_id": "eip-jf79ljt7" }, { "data": [ [ 1478693280, [ 0, 0 ] ], [ 1, 0 ], [ 0, 0 ] ], "eip_id": "eip-mw6n6wg0" } ], "meter_id": "uaffic" } ] }`

    result := []byte(str)
    err := json.Unmarshal(result, &response)
    fmt.Println(err)
}
func main() {
    var res GetLoadResponse
    Get(&res)
    //Get(res) // Will not be wrong, but res is null
    fmt.Println(res)
}
```

and then, I got this error:
 cannot unmarshal array into Go value of type main.LoadDataSet

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/ywFUu2MVNR

Image of JSON data:

[image]

Comment: The example JSON is invalid.  Please update the question with the correct text.

Comment: Can you do this on play.golang.org and share a link?

Comment: I have update ths json @Mellow Marmot

Comment: How to use play.golang.org to share a link? @Gaurav Ojha

Comment: @fishu Go to play.golang.org insert your code and press share. The Url looks like this: https://play.golang.org/p/ywFUu2MVNR ( this is your code )

Comment: https://play.golang.org/p/HCzefNMyzs

Comment: If I passing an  value to a function Get(response interface{}) will not be wrong, but value can't be changed when func return.

Comment: [Your json input layout doesn't match the struct definion](https://play.golang.org/p/oPT8SStdrY)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `data_set` in `meter_set` element is an array of `LoadDataSet`. Change your `LoadMeter` to:

```
type LoadMeter struct {                                                                          
      MeterID string              `json:"meter_id"`
      DataSet []LoadDataSet       `json:"data_set"`
}
```